# index confusing with python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

It's so confusing with the index of python and matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

I read an image I where I is an matrix. First, I used `plt.imshow()` to show the image.

There is a line on that image and I have the x- and y- coordinates of a line `L: x=[x0, x1, ..., xn], x=[y0, y1, ..., yn]`. So I can plot this line on the image by using `plt.plot(x,y)`. This step is still fine. At lease, the line shown on the image is correct.

However, when I plot the intensity values of image I at the location of the line L by using `plt.plot(I[x,y])`, it was obviously wrong!

I think the error might because that the coordinates of the line are having some inconsistency with the coordinates of the image. I tried `plt.plot(I[y,x])`, but it was still not correct.

So, first question, which should I use, `I[x,y] or I[y,x]`?

I observe the y axis on the `plt.imshow()` is from up to down. Could this be the reason that y-axis are flipped? Is x are also flipped? I'm totally confused with the coordinates orders...

Could anybody tell me where is wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: what is the type of `I`?

Answer (score 0):

> So, first question, which should I use, `I[x,y]` or `I[y,x]`?

Always use `I[x,y]`. This notation is standard in all computational libraries and branches of math.

`plt.plot(x,y)` expects a sequence. I believe, `I[a,b]` will return one pixel value not the values of the region.

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably guessed, there are two conventions at work here.

First, there is the mathematical convention of coordinates in graphs, where `(x,y) = (0,0)` is at the **lower** left corner:

[image: Mathematical convention]

Second, there is the convention used for arrays. Take this array for example:

```
img = [[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

That's how the image of the line would be stored. Now, `img[y, x] = img[0, 0]` refers to the **top** left corner!

When you use matplotlib's `imshow` function, which is used to show images, it makes the x- and y-axis show the pixel indices of the image matrix. Hence, (0,0) is the top left:

[image]

So, in order to align the coordinate systems, do like this:

```
plt.plot(np.flipud(I)[y, x])
```

(`np.flipud` flips the matrix upside down)